# how to make interaction client server with javascript calling php functions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to make multiple tables viewed and be editable from the site to the server in [my site](https://invisioncommunity.com).
I tried to use jquery ajax and it seems like fail
is there other way or my code was just bad?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".setitlive").click(function() { setitlive(1); });
});

function setitlive(value1) {
  var id=value1;
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\interactionclientserverwithphpandjavascript.php',
data: {functionname: 'setitlive', arguments: [id]};
}
</script>`
```

Interaction Client Server PHP code:

```
<?php   
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$id = $_POST['arguments'][0];
  switch($_POST["functionname"]){ 

    case 'setitlive': 
        public function setitlivee(  $id )
{
    $result = \IPS\Db::i()->update( 'cms_custom_database_26', array( 
'field_113' => 'live' ), array( 'primary_id_field="'.$id.'"'  ) );
    header("Refresh:0");
}
        break;      
}  

?>
```

HTML Header:

```
<form  method="POST">
button
<li class="ipsButton ipsButton_medium ipsButton_importantipsButton_fullWidth12">
    <a  title='{lang="accept"}' name="setitlive" id="setitlive" type="submit" onclick=" setitlive(); ">
        {lang="accept"}
    </a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, a window path isn't a URL. Your web server probably doesn't know how to find a file on your desktop unless you have a crazy configuration.

Put the target file in root of your project directory where your other php files are and then call it just by the file name and maybe a sub directory.

Once you've done that, if there's any further problems, please post it as a new question.

Let's say your php files are all in c:\www. Put that file in that directly and then...

```
 url : 'interactionclientserverwithphpandjavascript.php',
```